# RichTextBox1 reference to non shared object required an object reference

Tags: vb.net, winforms, richtextbox

```
Class DragDropRichTextBox
    Inherits RichTextBox

    Public Sub DragDropRichTextBox()
        Me.AllowDrop = True
        AddHandler Me.DragDrop, AddressOf richTextBox1_DragDrop
    End Sub

    Public Sub richTextBox1_DragDrop(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DragEventArgs)

        Dim filename As Object = e.Data.GetData("FileDrop")
        If filename IsNot Nothing Then
            Dim list = TryCast(filename, String())

            If list IsNot Nothing AndAlso Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(list(0)) Then
                RichTextBox1.Clear()
                RichTextBox1.LoadFile(list(0), RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText)
            End If
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Error on `RichTextBox1.clear()` and  `RichTextBox1.LoadFile(list(0), RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText)`

The error is:

> Reference to non-shared member requires an object reference

Comment: Your code doesn't really make sense.  If you're creating a custom class that inherits `RichTextBox` and you want custom functionality on a specific event then you override the method that raises that event.  In your case, it would appear that what you should be doing is overriding the `OnDragDrop` method. In that method, surely it only makes sense to refer to the current instance, which means using `Me`. What exactly do you think `RichTextBox1` is referring to in that context?

Comment: can u please help me with the code

Comment: As is the way at SO, I'm more than willing to help you fix the code if you try to write it but can't. You need to try first though. I've told you what you need to do. If you don't know how to do what I said, it's up to you to do some research to find out how. Have you tried to find out any information about the `DoDragDrop` method or overriding methods in general? You need to do all you can first, then ask for help if you're still unable to make it work.

Comment: @jmcilhinney  I think the OP is trying to modify the visibility of the `AllowDrop` property and the Events selection in the properties/events window. These are re-defined as `[Browsable(false)]]` in the .Net implementation, hence  only accessible in code. The `EnableAutoDragDrop` property only allows to drop text files as objects, not the content as text. The main purpose of the custom control is probably to provide standard (different?) functionality with these events.

Comment: If what you're trying to achieve is what I described in the previous comment, you need to define a `new` (`shadow`) event handler for the events you want to make visible and prefix the declaration with  `<EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Always), Browsable(True)>`. Then override the base event (`OnDragDrop`, `OnDragEnter` etc.), passing back the event to the base class (e.g, `MyBase.OnDragDrop(e)`) and raise the event right after.

Comment: Use `Me` instead of RichTextBox1.

Comment: Or, depending on the Version of VS just `Clear()` You only need Me it the meaning is ambiguous. If you mean `Public Sub DragDropRichTextBox()` to be the constructor then in vb.net it is `Public Sub New()` Using the name of the class for the Constructor is the C# way.